# graphviz 2.28 Voronoi-based technique

Tags: graphviz

I used graphviz neato 2.26 with `overlap = false` option and had graph the way i wanted it to be. But now i've upgraded to 2.28 and the graph is totally messed up.

The reference says:
`If Prism is not available, or the version of Graphviz is earlier than 2.28, "overlap=false" uses a Voronoi-based technique.`

So my question is: can i still use Voronoi-based technique in 2.28 and how? (I can not downgrade to 2.26).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -Goverlap=voronoi
or overlap=voronoi in the graph file